# Neural Network Forward Propagation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to solve this neural network problem found here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRznl.png]

How do I go ahead and calculate the forward propogate in this example? I've see examples of how to calculate the expected output but that is given here, and I'm note quite sure what I even need to do or start doing to calculate the forward propagate

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to understand your question so that it is self-contained. People aren't going to want to download & read something to understand your question. (You can still leave a link to the full pdf for more context for those who want it.)

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: @EngrStudent what difference does that make?

Answer (score 3):

Forward propogation is simply multiplying input with weights and add bias before applying activation fuction (sigmoid in here) at each node. There is no bias in this question.

$ W^{(1)}*x = z^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}
       \ W_{11}^{(1)} & \ W_{12}^{(1)} \\[0.3em]
       \ W_{21}^{(1)} & \ W_{22}^{(1)}  
     \end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}
       \ x_1  \\[0.3em]
       \ x_2   
     \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
       \ 0.5 & \ 0.1 \\[0.3em]
       \ 0.25 & 0.75  
     \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
       \ 1  \\[0.3em]
       \ 0   
     \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix} \ 0.5  \\[0.3em] \ 0.25  \end{bmatrix}$

$ a^{(2)}= sigm(z^{(1)}) = sigm(\begin{bmatrix} \ 0.5  \\[0.3em] \ 0.25  \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix} \ 0.6225  \\[0.3em] \ 0.5622 \end{bmatrix}   $

$ W^{(2)}*a^{(2)} = z^{(2)} = \begin{bmatrix}
       \ W_{11}^{(2)} & \ W_{12}^{(2)}  
     \end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix}
       \ a^{(2)}_1  \\[0.3em]
       \ a^{(2)}_2   
     \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
       \ 0.95*0.6225 + 0.5622*1.0 
     \end{bmatrix} = 1.1536 $

$ a^{(3)}= sigm(z^{(2)}) = sigm(1.1536) =  0.7602  $

This is your output, and assume that your cost function is

$ C = \frac{1}{2}(a^{(3)} -y )^2$

where y is expected output = 0.5, and output error term derived as,

$ δ^{(3)} = \frac{dC}{dz^{(2)}} = (a^{(3)} -y ).* a^{(3)}.*(1-a^{(3)}) = (0.7602 - 0.5) .*0.7602.*(1-0.7602) = 0.0474$

where '.*' is element-wise product and $a^{(3)}.*(1-a^{(3)})$ comes from derivation of sigmoid. I've assumed that error term calculated with respect to $ z$,not $ a$. If that is the case the derivation changes a little bit. Now back propogate $ δ^{(3)}$, to find $ δ_{2}^{(2)}$

$ δ_{2}^{(2)} =  \frac{dC}{dz^{(2)}} * \frac{dz^{(2)}}{dz_{2}^{(1)}} =  δ^{(3)} * \frac{dz^{(2)}}{dz_{2}^{(1)}} $

let's drive the second term before we continue

$ \frac{dz^{(2)}}{dz_{2}^{(1)}} = W_{12}^{(2)}.*a_{2}^{(2)}.*(1-a_{2}^{(2)})$ from $ z^{(2)}= W^{(2)}*sigm(z^{(1)}) $

now we can evaluate previous equation,
$ δ_{2}^{(2)} =  \frac{dC}{dz^{(2)}} * \frac{dz^{(2)}}{dz_{2}^{(1)}} =  δ^{(3)} * W_{12}^{(2)}.*a_{2}^{(2)}.*(1-a_{2}^{(2)}) = 0.0474 * 1.0 * 0.5622 * (1-0.5622) = 0.0117 $

You can see that how error term diminishes quickly during back propogation if we use sigmoid activation(or hyperbolic tangent).